# django tar generation on request

Tags: python, django, django-views, tar

Greetings,
By using Django, I want to generate a tar.gz which contains the files below, and render a tar.gz file:

Content from an Ubuntu server:

```
/home/user/myfolder
/home/user/image.jpg
an xml file from www.mysite.com/foo.xml (which is a dynamicly generated xml file.
```

Rendered tar.gz file

```
myfolder/
         content/
          .....
image.jpg
foo.xml
```

What would be the best way to do this inside achieve this as a Django view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) module is probably a good place to start.

You would probably want to cache the file somewhere in the filesystem to save yourself from too much work. There's no reason to regenerate the file if the contents haven't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **django-tarview** (install via `pip` [from PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tarview/), or get it from [github](https://github.com/luckydonald/django-tarview))

Extend `tarview.views.BaseTarView` and implement `get_files`:

```
from tarview.views import BaseTarView

class TarView(BaseTarView):
    def get_files(self):
        return [File(open('test_file.txt'), name="test_file.txt"),
            ContentFile(b"I am a text file", name="text.txt")]
```